# Definition on apt vs apt-get

Tags: apt

Since the man page on `apt` is not clear on this subject, can you tell me if the `apt-get` *--purge* option can be used on `apt` too. **PLEASE NOTE**: I'm referring to the option *--purge* and not to the command ***purge*** that is used without the two dashes.

So, can the syntax: `apt-get --purge autoremove` be used on `apt` too like this: `apt --purge autoremove`?

And if not, what is the equivalent command for `apt`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Try for yourself...

```
$ apt --purge --simulate autoremove
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-5.8.0-43* linux-headers-5.8.0-43-generic*
  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic* linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic*
  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic* linux-tools-5.8.0-43*
  linux-tools-5.8.0-43-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Purg linux-headers-5.8.0-43-generic [5.8.0-43.49]
Purg linux-headers-5.8.0-43 [5.8.0-43.49]
Purg linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic [5.8.0-43.49]
Purg linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic [5.8.0-43.49]
Purg linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic [5.8.0-43.49]
Purg linux-tools-5.8.0-43-generic [5.8.0-43.49]
Purg linux-tools-5.8.0-43 [5.8.0-43.49]
```

The `--simulate` flag makes testing without risk easy.

Comment: Your example uses `apt-get` though. Since my question is about `apt`, I guess you mean I can use the same options for `apt` too, including *--simulate*. Right?

Comment: Typo fixed. That should clarify a bit.